# How change SVG image colors with inline attribute?

Tags: html, svg

I have SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
     <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"/>
     <path fill="white" d="M19.43 12.98c.04-.32.07-.64.07-.98s-.03-.66-.07-.98l2.11-1.65c.19-.15.24-.42.12-.64l-2-3.46c-.12-.22-.39-.3-.61-.22l-2.49 1c-.52-.4-1.08-.73-1.69-.98l-.38-2.65c-.03-.24-.24-.42-.49-.42h-4c-.25 0-.46.18-.49.42l-.38 2.65c-.61.25-1.17.59-1.69.98l-2.49-1c-.23-.09-.49 0-.61.22l-2 3.46c-.13.22-.07.49.12.64l2.11 1.65c-.04.32-.07.65-.07.98s.03.66.07.98l-2.11 1.65c-.19.15-.24.42-.12.64l2 3.46c.12.22.39.3.61.22l2.49-1c.52.4 1.08.73 1.69.98l.38 2.65c.03.24.24.42.49.42h4c.25 0 .46-.18.49-.42l.38-2.65c.61-.25 1.17-.59 1.69-.98l2.49 1c.23.09.49 0 .61-.22l2-3.46c.12-.22.07-.49-.12-.64l-2.11-1.65zm-7.43 2.52c-1.93 0-3.5-1.57-3.5-3.5s1.57-3.5 3.5-3.5 3.5 1.57 3.5 3.5-1.57 3.5-3.5 3.5z"/></svg>
```

And usage in HTML:

```
<img src="client/res/ic_edit_24px.svg" style="width: 16px; height: 16px;"/>
```

Or

```
<svg width="16" height="16">
    <image xlink:href="svg.svg" src="client/res/ic_edit_24px.svg" width="16" height="16"/>
</svg>
```

How can I change stroke or fill color with attribute? I can't use jquery and css, only inline attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`CSS Filters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

### Example :

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; filter:invert(100%)"/>
```

Ps : this long src is the data uri of your svg as I didn't want to upload it but it will also work with

```
<img src="client/res/ic_edit_24px.svg" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; filter:invert(100%);"/>
```

Comment: Cool but how i can set "#CD5C5C" for first path and "#FFA07A" for second path? :)

Comment: Then I'd say your only option is to modify original svg. I think you can't alter `svg` rendered into `img` tag (at least without js hacks)